# indexing this query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Part of query:

```
    FROM
        pm_data AS pmdata
        LEFT JOIN messages as pm
            ON pmdata.msg_id = pm.msg_id
        LEFT JOIN users as usr
            ON (usr.uid = pm.reciever_id || usr.uid = pm.sender_id)
    WHERE

        (
            pmdata.sender_id = 541839243781
            AND
            pmdata.sender_isdeleted = 1
        )
        OR
        (
            pmdata.reciever_id = 541839243781
            AND
            pmdata.reciever_isDeleted = 1
        )

    ORDER BY pm.created_at DESC
```

at the moment i have only added

- index1(msg_id)
- index2(sender_isDeleted)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: this query takes 0,0014 when in other situtations it takes almost 0,004 to load... i thought if i can index it/optimize it better for better load times

Comment: @Marco right now i am building the messaging system so only dummy data but that doesnt mean i dont need to index the tables, right?

Comment: @Marco I think his Id fields are already indexed if the are auto column. From the naming convention it seems they are auto column

Comment: @Shiplu in other cases where the WHERE part is something else for inbox/sent messages pages it takes about 0,004 so i think i can do this for this situation as well(its deleted messages page)

Comment: Using indexes is a "balancing" problem: too few could make a query slow, but too many can result in same problem!! So, use indexes when you really need them! And "when you need" is also related to the amount and type of data...

Comment: @Shiplu: I don't know, we're just guessing... so you could be right or not :)

Comment: actually pm.reciever_id, pm.sender_id, pmdata.sender_id and pmdata.reciever_id are random generated numbers... they are next to the AUTO_INCREMENT column(id)

Comment: show your schema for `pmdata` and `messages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query only, useful indexes are:

- pmdata(sender_id)
- pmdata(reciever_id)
- messages(msg_id)
- users(uid)

This query does not need what you mentioned:

- index1(msg_id)
- index2(sender_isDeleted)